# Can you have a single domain across 2 servers within Hyper-V Manager?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, hyper-v, windows-server

I am running a Hyper-V lab for a client to test the functionality of a Powershell script and due to memory constraints, I would like to move my file and database VM servers off of my main desktop PC to my laptop. I set up Hyper-V on the laptop, and successfully exported/imported the VM's into the other Hyper-V server. I can boot them, all the configuration and files are intact however, I am predictably having trouble reconnecting to the domain they were a part of prior to the move. I understand I need an External virtual switch to handle that communication, as internal and private will not reach outside of the Hyper-V server they reside in. Obviously I would prefer to not use an external, but this is strictly to continue testing. I've trouble-shooted entering different DNS server values from the client machine's IPv4 properties and changing the virtual switch to External for the existing Hyper-V server, and re-register the DNS records on the DC. All result in the same error when I try to connect to the domain: "(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR) The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc."... "The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS".

In summary, I want to move a VM from the first server listed to the second, and then re-connect to the domain they were part of previously. Both machines are just running Windows 10, not Windows Servers, if that matters. Another note, I can do remote sessions from the desktop to the laptop just fine which would lead to believe this is not related to a firewall. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The best it to set up a VLAN. If you can't do that, change the network class of your AD lab machine (192.168.55.x ?) to another in order to avoid conflicts.
Your DNS server has to be AD to make your machines connecting to it.
And last but not least, if you're on 2 different hyperV servers, you have to use external switch in hyperV:
https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/05/04/hyper-v-private-networks.aspx